# Función que pueda validar argumentos no definidos

Tags: php, php7

Quiero validar los campos de mi formulario en servidor con una función pero no tengo ni idea **cómo puedo enviar argumentos a una función aunque la variable no esté definida.**
Un ejemplo de lo que pretendo:

```
function requeridos($variables)
{
    foreach ($variables as $var) 
    {
        if (!isset($var)) json_response("Uno de los campos no lo recibí");
        if (empty($var)) json_response("Uno de los campos esta vacío");
    }   
}

// titulo no definido
// mensaje recibido del js
requeridos([ $_POST['titulo'], $_POST['mensaje'] ])
```

Respuesta de php:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: titulo in C:\xampp\htdocs\...

Sé que puedo validar si existe con `isset()` pero quisiera automatizar este proceso de alguna manera ya que en todos los .php requiero hacer siempre esta comprobación y me queda bastante "sucio".

Aceptaría alternativas, de antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes repasar con un foreach el propio `$_POST` comprobando si todos los valores son diferentes de cadena vacía (no es isset, sino comparar si está vacío). También, en la llamada js podrías meter todas las variables que intervengan (imagino que del formulario) en un objeto, y enviar ese objeto en el $_POST. Y así, en el php comprobar sólo cada propiedad de ese objeto en lugar de todo el $_POST. Así quedaría más ordenadito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Importante:** la función `requeridos` no devuelve absolutamente nada, porque se observa en la publicación la intención de dejar los mensajes en función de los resultados de la validación.
>
> Lo ideal sería que la función devolviera un valor de tipo booleano (`bool`) para indicar que las validaciones superaron las pruebas exitosamente.

La forma en el que puedes automatizarlo de acuerdo a lo que indicas en la publicación es de la siguiente manera, pero no la única forma que existe.

```php
/**
 * @param string ...$fields
 * @return void
 */
function requeridos(string ...$fields): void {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$field])) {
            json_response("'{$field}' es requerido");
            continue;
        }

        if (empty(trim($_POST[$field]))) {
            json_response("El campo '{$field}' está vacío");
        }
    }
}
```

Tomando en cuenta de que aceptas alternativas de soluciones:

> Aceptaría alternativas, de antemano, muchas gracias.

De esta forma, la función `requeridos` puede aceptar una cantidad variable de argumentos que puedes iterar y comprobar que existen como índices en la variable superglobal `$_POST`.

Es decir, lo puedes utilizar sin problemas:

```php
requeridos('titulo', 'mensaje');
```

---

**Leyenda:**

- `$fields`: se traduce como "campos".
- `$field`: se traduce como "campo".

Comment: Respondiendo a la cita importante, si la función `requeridos()` en la primera coincidencia llama a la función `json_response()`, esta función de respuesta imprime un error formateado en json y detiene la ejecución del código significa que no continúa con el proceso. La función `requeridos()` prácticamente se encarga de permitir o no el flujo del código.

Comment: En cuanto al código, es interesante la solución y tengo toda la culpa de no haber especificado de que también recibo una imagen obviamente en `$_FILES`. Sin embargo me crearé otra función similar pero que valide sólo archivos. Muchas gracias Sr. Luna

Answer (score 0):

Es porque al llamar a la función `requeridos` estás llamando a la variable `$_POST` con índices que no existen.

```
function requeridos($variable, $indices)
{
    foreach ($indices as $i)
    {
        if (!isset($variable[$i])) json_response("Uno de los campos no lo recibí");
        if (empty($variable[$i])) json_response("Uno de los campos esta vacío");
    }   
}

requeridos($_POST, array('titulo', 'mensaje', 'etc'));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cesar, si puedes observar en el comentario del Sr. Luna, indiqué que algunos campos son `$_FILES`, gracias a tu respuesta puedo usar una función para indicarle que tipo de campo es y sus clave. Las 2 respuestas me fueron de ayuda.